# cocoapods - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, linker-errors, afnetworking-2

I am getting the following error:

`ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I uninstalled AFNetworking and did not get the error. I reinstalled and do get the error.

I am using AFNetworking 2.5.

I used cocoapods to install/uninstall.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any linker flags in your project? Because CocoaPods needs that you set up $(inherited) in that parameter of building

Comment: Yes, I did set up $(inherited) and that fixed a different issue and then I got this problem. I have tried installing AFNetworking using no version, '~> 2.5' (that was there originally) and also '2.5'. I uninstalled ALL pods and one by one installed and rebuilt the project incase there was a conflict and this only happens for AFNetworking. I have deleted derived data, I also have set derived data to relative. These are all possible solutions I found but none resolved my issue.

Comment: Haha! My issue was I was trying to run on pbxproj instead of xcworkspace! Doh!

Answer (score 4):

After 14 hours of debugging and the help of 8 different developers we found the problem! I hope this answer helps someone in the future. It was NOT an AFNetworking error at all. The problem was one view controller implementation file did not have the target selected in Target Memberships. AFNetworking was the first #import in that view controller and that is why it was being singled out in the error.

If you have this error and you have tried all the common solutions, go through your view controllers and check for this setting.